# Import PDFs for RAG with metadata

Tags: pdf, streamlit, langchain, large-language-model, retrieval-augmented-generation

I have built a small chatbot with Langchain and Streamlit. A classic LLM with RAG for practising. At the moment it only reads multiple PDFs so that the documents can be chatted with. For the moment, I read in the PDF straightforward.

```
import streamlit as st
from pypdf import PdfReader

def get_pdf_text(pdf_docs):
    text = ""
    for pdf in pdf_docs:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf)
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    return text

def get_text_chunks(text):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(...)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text)
    return chunks

pdf_docs = st.file_uploader('load PDFs', accept_multiple_files=True)
```

With this method, all PDFs are added as one large text and then split. Metadata such as document name or page are lost in the process. That's why I wanted to try it with the PyPDFLoader delivered with Langchain.

```
import streamlit as st
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

def get_pdf_text(pdf_docs):
    pdf_reader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_docs)
    text = pdf_reader.load_and_split()
    return text

pdf_docs = st.file_uploader('load PDFs', accept_multiple_files=True)

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
```

However, it looks like the PyPDFLoader does not work directly with the FileUploader of Streamlit, but requires a path to the PDF.

Is there a workaround to use the FileUploader from Streamlit? Or a better alternative to extract text with metadata from PDFs?